# Upload multiple files using Files Field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, filefield

Here i have class models:

**models.py**

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(
        upload_to='uploaded',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

and i have this in my **admin.py**

```
class ParameterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = Parameter
```

and i add it in my **forms.py** so it can select more then one file

```
class ParameterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParameterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['files '] = forms.FileField(
            widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        )
```

But, after i try to choose and select multiple files via django admin.. Not all files are uploaded and it only upload one latest selected file..

How can i upload multiple files via django admin..?
I don't need views.py and html from.. i just need django admin can upload multiple files.. Simple

Answer (score 1):

You should override save_model function of ParameterAdmin like this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
    for f in files:
        instance = Parameter(files=f)
        instance.save()
```

It will save all files.

Answer (score -1):

A FileField only stores a single file. If you want multiple files, you need either multiple fields (but unless each of those files as a distinct specific role it's a bad design) or a distinct `ParameterFile` model with a foreign key on `Parameter` and a `FileField`, and then use an `InlineModelAdmin`.

Comment: Nope! He need to push 1 button, and choose 100 files to upload! He don't want to push "Upload button" 100 times! So.. it's not about inline.... it's about multiple file upload